# How to make a draggable/expandable bottom navbar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a navbar which can be expandable.
The goal is to show 5 icons, then 3 more when I tap on the burger icon.

There is some screen that can help for the result I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BottomAppBar` widget in combination with the `FloatingActionButton` widget, here is an example, do some customization as you wish:

```
class ExpandableNavbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpandableNavbarState createState() => _ExpandableNavbarState();
}

class _ExpandableNavbarState extends State<ExpandableNavbar> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _icons = [
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {}),
    ];

    List<Widget> _expandedIcons = [
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.email), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.help), onPressed: () {}),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("My Content"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(_isExpanded ? Icons.close : Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
          });
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 8.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: _icons,
            ),
            if (_isExpanded)
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: _expandedIcons,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Variant without Floating Button:

```
class ExpandableNavbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpandableNavbarState createState() => _ExpandableNavbarState();
}

class _ExpandableNavbarState extends State<ExpandableNavbar> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _icons = [
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(_isExpanded ? Icons.close : Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
            });
          }),
    ];

    List<Widget> _expandedIcons = [
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.email), onPressed: () {}),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.help), onPressed: () {}),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("My Content"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 8.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: _icons,
            ),
            if (_isExpanded)
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: _expandedIcons,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see how it works [here](https://preview.flutlab.io/9be4cea6-ce29-4c96-9faa-c903b8c80e2b/r61f1bplacgwcgyy15ez/#/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know how is it possible to put the icons below and not on the side when you tap on the button?

Comment: @MICHELBaptiste sure, I updated my code and paste link to functional prototype. BTW, I use FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked, but you can change and customize this button as you wish

Comment: Thank you so much, the preview doesn't work for me, but at least i tried it and it's exacly what i want. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use Column with two Row on `bottomNavigationBar`. Also you may like `Wrap` widget. You can wrap each item with tappable widget to perform action `body`.

```dart
class AppNT extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppNT({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppNT> createState() => _AppNTState();
}

class _AppNTState extends State<AppNT> {
  bool expand = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Tab $i',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      expand = !expand;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz)),
            ],
          ),
          if (expand)
            Row( // you can add some animatedWidget
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Tab ${i + 4}',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```